# Is this algorithm technically O(1) time?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

O(1) means "constant time", so is this max algorithm technically O(1) time?

```
int max (int x, int y)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 100000000000000000000000000; ++k); // useless for-loop
    return (x > y ? x : y);
}
```

Comment: Yes. (too short)

Comment: This is not an algorithm; this a code chunk.

Comment: Compiler may not even generate any code for that for loop, since it is not doing anything and updating local variable `k`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is constant time.

I understand your concern: constant time doesn't necessarily mean that it is fast, as your contrived example demonstrates (even though User 104 is right about the compiler not generating any code for the loop).  But a heck of a lot more often than not, big O notation tells us all we need to know.  And it is relatively easy to compute.

Bottom line: Big O notation is all about asymptotics.  If the Big O notation does not seem to agree with your intuition, then check your analysis again or check your intuition.  Repeat at least three times.  And if it still fails, then discuss it with your professor.  And only then if your professor says so, you should do a deeper analysis than big O (which will be difficult).